# Cannot connect to mssql database within Docker container - OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009)

Tags: python, database, docker, epicorerp

I am trying to connect to a database within a Docker container, however, I get the following error:

```
OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (DB)\n')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

The code works fine as a standalone script, e.g. I can connect to the database fine using no Docker container. However, when I try to connect via a Docker container the above error arises. My code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase
import os

# Get environment variables
user = os.getenv('USER', 'user')
password = os.getenv('PASSWORD', 'password')
host = os.getenv('HOST', 'DB')
database = os.getenv('DB', 'Epicor')
port = os.getenv('PORT', 5432)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = f"mssql+pymssql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL
    # Uncomment for debug info of db creation
    # echo=True
)
```

(Part of) my Dockerfile:

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

version: "3"

services:
    database:
        build: ./database
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        networks:
            - test
        restart: unless-stopped
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

I have tried to google the problem before, I found a SO post detailing the exact same problem, but the solution that was given I tried to apply in my Docker file (extra_hosts) but to no avail. The solution also did not work for the OP of that post

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server here and you state "mssql" in your title, but some of your question implies you are attempting to connect to PostgreSQL, not SQL Server. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry. I use mssql to connect to Epicor. PostgreSQL contained my test database. I will remove the wrong tags and edit the question

Comment: SQL Server, by default, runs on port 1433; are you sure your SQL Server instance is running on port 5432?

Comment: Actually I think it does run on port 1433 now that you mention it, but I am unable to check if it is the case at the moment. Running it on port 1433 results in the same error, unfortunately.